# TypeScript confused about function argument types

Tags: typescript

Here is a function whose argument types must be compatible with the properties and values of an object:

```js
type MyFunction = <T extends keyof typeof myObject>(
  name: T,
  value: (typeof myObject)[T][number]
) => void;

const myObject = {
  strings: ["one", "two"],
  numbers: [1, 2],
};

const myFunction: MyFunction = (name, value) => {
  if (!myObject[name].includes(value)) {
    // do something            ^^^^^
  }
};
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiBiBXAdgY2ASwPbKgXigB4AVKCAD2AmQBMBnKAawhCwDMpRJ2oBbEAPIAjAFYR0APgAUAKChRkAQ14QAXFGIAaOVABuigDaI1UKVwg9+wsegCUAbWIBde8kS8hEAE5OZt-BJ6WBg0ANwyMqg4dMB8gqLisQQA3joxXhjIAOZ06vYARDgQ+ZpQ+cAA7lj5Ttrybh7euVD2AIylAEy1MgC+4ZHRsfxIaJg46nAj6Ni4BFJKKqX6RhD+eIGp8ltQGBxSAIRWCeiuyhBOAHSZqEY0EHRSy8a2-pvbWwD0H1A0WFB0WBUwAAFpksjptj1euEgA)

Here is the error message I get (on `value`):

```
Argument of type 'string | number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.
  Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'.
```

I can understand why TypeScript is complaining here but adding a `switch` statement or an `if` statement on `name` still results in the same error:

```js
const myFunction: MyFunction = (name, value) => {
  switch (name) {
    case "strings": {
      if (!myObject[name].includes(value)) {
        // do something            ^^^^^
      }
      break;
    }
  }
};
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiBiBXAdgY2ASwPbKgXigB4AVKCAD2AmQBMBnKAawhCwDMpRJ2oBbEAPIAjAFYR0APgAUAKChRkAQ14QAXFGIAaOVABuigDaI1UKVwg9+wsegCUAbWIBde8kS8hEAE5OZt-BJ6WBg0ANwyMqg4dMB8gqLisQQA3joxXhjIAOZ06vYARDgQ+ZpQ+cAA7lj5Ttrybh7euVD2AIylAEy1MgC+4ZHRsfxIaJg46nAj6Ni4BFJKKqX6RhD+eIGp8hgcUgCEVgnorsoQTgB0mahGNBB0UsvGtv6b8lAA9G9QNFhQdFgqwAAFpksjoer1wkA)

Am I missing something here?

Comment: You're missing that TS doesn't constrain generics to a single member of a union type; it can be the full union [as shown here](//tsplay.dev/WGBZkm).  The "correct" way to represent this is either to refactor to generics as shown in [ms/TS#47109](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109) (which has the same issue but is explicitly supported), or to make it non-generic and do case analysis, depending on which of your two approaches you'd like to use.  [As shown here](//tsplay.dev/NnB1aN).  Does that fully address the q? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz Thank you for your comments, I think it does fully address the question.

Comment: I’ll write up an answer when I get a chance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now there's now way to say that a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameter can be [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to a *single member* of a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) like `"strings" | "numbers"`.  It is always possible that someone can call `myFunction()` with the type parameter specified as that full union type, allowing the arguments to fail to be restricted in the way that you expected.  Like this, for example:

```
myFunction(Math.random() < 0.99 ? "strings" : "numbers", 3); // okay
```

That call is allowed.  The type argument is inferred as `"strings" | "numbers"`, and there is a 99% chance that `"strings"` will be passed as `name` to the function at runtime, while the `value` will always be the number `3`.  So there's a 99% chance that you're doing something the compiler doesn't want to support, like looking for a number in an array of strings.

There are various open feature requests looking for something better here.  The one I usually refer to is [microsoft/TypeScript#27808](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27808), which, if implemented, would let you say something like

```
// NOT VALID TS, DON'T TRY THIS
type MyFunction = <K oneof keyof MyObject>( 
  name: K, value: MyObject[K][number]
) => void;
```

where `oneof` represents a different sort of constraint that `extends`.  Right now this isn't part of the language.

This is related to why the compiler complains.  It does not try to relate `name` and `value` to each other.  When passing `value` to `myObject[name].includes()`, it fails to see any correlation, and instead tries to figure out what `myObject[name].includes()` should accept in general.  That function is assignable to `((x: string) => boolean) | ((x: number) => boolean)`, a union of functions.  The only safe thing to pass to a union of functions is an [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) of its parameters (see [the TS3.3 release notes](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-3.html#improved-behavior-for-calling-union-types)), so the compiler wants you to pass in a `string & number`, which is both a `string` *and* a `number`.  But that's not possible, and is equivalent to [the `never` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-never-type).  And `value` is only known to be a `string` *or* a `number`, so it fails.

If you want to proceed we'll need to refactor somewhat.

---

If you want to have a single line like `(!myObject[name].includes(value))` inside the implementation, that works for both `"strings"` and `"numbers"`, then you will need to keep the function generic, but refactor to a form as described in [microsoft/TypeScript#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109).  The approach is to represent everything in terms of a "basic" key-value interface type, and generic [indexes](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) into either that type, or into [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) over that type.  You can read that GitHub issue for a full description of how and why that works.  The refactoring for your example code looks like this:

```
// basic key-value interface
interface MyObjEl {
  strings: string;
  numbers: number;
}

// mapped type over the basic interface
type MyObject = { [K in keyof MyObjEl]: MyObjEl[K][] };

// explicit typing for myObject
const myObject: MyObject = {
  strings: ["one", "two"],
  numbers: [1, 2],
};

// generic indexing into mapped type
type MyFunction = <K extends keyof MyObjEl>(
  name: K,
  value: MyObjEl[K]
) => void;

const myFunction: MyFunction = (name, value) => {
  if (!myObject[name].includes(value)) { } // okay
};
```

That works because `myObject[name].includes` is now seen to be the generic non-union type `(x: MyObjEl[K]) => boolean`.  And since `value` is of type `MyObjEl[K]`, it works.  These types are equivalent to the generic versions you were using, but the compiler lost track of the correlation there, whereas here it sees it.

Note that this means the function can *still* be called the bad way:

```
myFunction(Math.random() < 0.99 ? "strings" : "numbers", 3);
```

This is working as intended as per [microsoft/TypeScript#48730](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/48730), so all we can say is "be careful" until and unless something like microsoft/TypeScript#27808 is implemented.

---

On the other hand, if you want to use case analysis inside your function implementation and do different things for different `name` inputs, then you don't want to use generics at all.  Instead you'd want to make the function accept a [destructured discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-6.html#control-flow-analysis-for-destructured-discriminated-unions) of [tuple-typed rest parameters](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#rest-parameters-with-tuple-types).  Like this:

```
type MyObject = typeof myObject;

type MyFunctionParams = { [K in keyof MyObject]:
  [name: K, value: MyObject[K][number]]
}[keyof MyObject];

// type MyFunctionParams = 
//   [name: "strings", value: string] | [name: "numbers", value: number]

type MyFunction = (...[name, value]: MyFunctionParams) => void;

const myFunction: MyFunction = (name, value) => {
  switch (name) {
    case "strings": {
      value.toUpperCase(); // okay
      if (!myObject[name].includes(value)) {

      }
      break;
    }
    case "numbers": {
      value.toFixed(2); // okay
    }
  }
};
```

Here we've made the compiler compute that the `[name, value]` rest parameter should be of the [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions) type `["strings", string] | ["numbers", number]`, and that by checking `name`, the apparent type of `value` can be narrowed.

As a bonus, the function can no longer be called the bad way:

```
myFunction(Math.random() < 0.99 ? "strings" : "numbers", 3); // error
```

That's because `["strings" | "numbers", string | number]` does not match `["strings", string] | ["numbers", number]`.

---

So there you go.  You could either keep your function generic but refactor to a version the compiler can understand, or make your function non-generic using a discriminated union.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEApeIA2AvJBvAUEkvAPbBQAuSYAngPIBGAVhPFQLx6FFKUBOAS2ABzKAC4kAbQBEZCNIA0SaRQDuJaQF0F3IsACuYBhD7ipARiUAmbdwC+AbnzO94aHERI6g4V11IKGhhkAFl6ZlYOAKCIEgAzanCWNid-QOCkMIAxfWA2ATIkTgAeAGkkCAAPCghgABMoJABrCBp4zKTIgD4ACn9XSAlSnR4eADdMfQgJMMZkiklSzUkDIxNNfwBKIq6kMZIBOtTR0nIqWhy8igLgGZpL-MLOHtBIJQmMKe32XYJRoigqgEFHgAAskC83Ns-v8iOgoMhpPwhKJpBIYbCiAIEj0AIS0OaRFZuTQAOiE8E+dWgPQ+X2h-UxAHomUg6iReCRIBRQSjGaM7PyeAw+BAQE0nJikILYTKeI4XDwWUgACq8xroDAYJACRoIRAwGp1JAMfRUHkmCAAcj1SAAnHaAKTEUEgPLIdpxEACT6i-wXXKPYA9EIgHmkvhu9lgHrbYpIAAMpIdSAA-MpkSIoNIkBJpKtjKZFEgAMybSXS5zcV7uBChADKKvrABYAOzmBN2gDitRMAngWT4XPr8EjIPBBH8QhqfC9nlmzAAotqMTxM6IJOuK6MCyYzLu+NvK2kYh1CWwingpOUhM1Wu0F0xl5o7nNl4tlpppcceKdKIlzwoV8IgvThVwBChBCzCQZDkYsVHULQRn+A8zEkSwkBsZCiAVE8MmyQNrieJAygqapagaO82gSR9l16RkayGbDxkmaYzyXDAPy2HY9gOI5FThMh-wDK4bjuB4iOAS9ITePZWO+X5GWxCF8U6NhiUgMkKSpGk6QgTZoUrAUfyIESgxDMNQQjKMuVjEjE2TO00wzSCUWzXNlFQ4syx-QVqzcWA60yRsW3bTse2APt4AAYS5GAzQgQcuUXSpdWuERH0iPxRnSUI1KiXL2gJECKBM6J8KSZdL1wa8dSklpqPY+YXyaoklhWQxCy-XDRiZAAqKdgBnOc8rfFdGXXMwtwYzq9wkA8jzsJB-H8P9zny9FatvBqH3ylraM49ruuqibXOgqRZEi+C1A0WxYVQmCMKw-w5SIPqmQE8q8okm5L1IqoanqRodpo-L6PutwmMZPTgKfQ6NlGBTeMOMq1sSH6yHEwjfueGt3nknjwOIISqAAfWK+ZNsWOqqN2wD9sq+HJGOzgKciI8sRxXFyfyjSIC0vIdKgWl5IZRlXu-f17mxsgLPDSN6lsuMHJTdMkTO1EPPzWaiyUHzFT8gZa08ABVYAbmikAEQAQVADAaCgXVsp4XLWtAr6ivysrXYI0SyAABRASMwEaMCtvq+9QfpsRGT5pi5M+NjMvU9qD00BH5UkEG3YoTQj38ZUfelv3gED4PQ+W3rWSIOOXKg1F8cTzcNa-AAfKRGM8nXs0bqZ5p1jOiDw76Zak55SQnvne-5rGS7L8AoCR-YUc+tGzMk2eg2kvGE6+QmJqBccIRrBkpXhRFJrRLgpSIPTSQoEgTZgYI+EthFYwcJBlRIJoQBoIVOYqTZupGsAtKT6GpMLPSBlnZSglrCEUYoJRCngb+K2iIvLogAbvCA98SBZAEJUCAdQehWHLF-VkP8-4oPFi9Mq68bhyysgraMdl4xJlVnXNyOY8xeT1uQ5UJghx8ANs4OwQA)

Comment: Thank you for this comprehensive answer!